# PHP DOM - Get all option value by select name

Tags: php, dom

I need to get "option" values from a site. But there are more than one "select". How do I get "option" values by "Select name" value . (get all option value by select name=ctl02$dlOgretimYillari)

```
<select name="ctl02$dlOgretimYillari" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl02$dlOgretimYillari\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl02_dlOgretimYillari" class="NormalBlack">
            <option selected="selected" value="-40">2016-2017</option>

        </select>
```

My Code :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$options_value = array();
$options_name = array();
$options_selected = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('option') as $option) {
    array_push($options_value, $option->getAttribute('value'));
    array_push($options_selected, $option->getAttribute('selected'));
    array_push($options_name, $option->nodeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get all option value by select name=ctl02$dlOgretimYillari

The solution using [***DOMXPath::query***](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) method:

```
$content = '<select name="ctl02$dlOgretimYillari" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(\'__doPostBack(\'ctl02$dlOgretimYillari\',\'\')\', 0)" id="ctl02_dlOgretimYillari" class="NormalBlack">           <option selected="selected" value="-40">2016-2017</option>        </select>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors();
$doc->loadXML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//select[@name='ctl02\$dlOgretimYillari']/option/@value");

// outputting first option value
print_r($nodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

The output:

```
-40
```

---

For additional condition: *How do I get the value of the option text?*

```
...
$nodes = $xpath->query("//select[@name='ctl02\$dlOgretimYillari']/option/text()");
...
```

Comment: In the "$ content" variable I just need to specify select. How can I do without giving the option part?

Comment: Note: The contents of this page is the content of the page I have executed with curl.

Comment: what does mean your sentence : *I just need to specify select. How can I do without giving the option part* ?

Comment: <Option selected = "selected" value = "- 40"> 2016-2017 </ option>
It is not necessary to specify this part. It must be dynamic.

Comment: so let it be dynamic, the solution will work. `$nodes` will contain all the option's values, then, all you need is to iterate though it via simple `foreach` loop

Comment: I understand. But I do not know how to make this part dynamic.
$content = '<select name="ctl02$dlOgretimYillari" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(\'__doPostBack(\'ctl02$dlOgretimYillari\',\'\')\', 0)" id="ctl02_dlOgretimYillari" class="NormalBlack">           <option selected="selected" value="-40">2016-2017</option>        </select>';

Comment: Yes Sir, Its worked. So, How do I get the value of the option text?

Comment: @mrdeveloper, use `child::text()` location path, see my update. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

@RomanPerekhrest 's answer definitely solved the initial question!

But in my case I needed to get all the **selected** values, so here's the solution for anyone with the same problem:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//select[@name='ctl02\$dlOgretimYillari']/option[@selected]/@value");

// Printing
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    print_r($node->nodeValue);
}
```